# How do I get bytearray from $.ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web, blob

So, here's the deal. I need to download a zip file from an API and move it to another server. If I just type the url on the browser, it gives me the zip file I want, but I need this process to be automated, since I'm moving a lot of files.

So my question mainly is, is there a way to get this file as bytearray and post it to my server? My backend application is using ASP.NET MVC.

The code I currently have, but doesn't work, is this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.mercadolibre.com/shipment_labels?shipment_ids=" + mlOrders[269].shipping.id + "&savePdf=Y&access_token=" + token,
    async: false,                                    
    success: function (zipFile) {
        console.log(zipFile);
        $.post(
            "/Home/GetPDF", { zipFile: zipFile },
            function () {
                alert('ok');
            }
        );
    },
    error: function (errorObject) {
        console.log("FILURE AT /orders/{id}/shipments ->", errorObject);
    }
});
```

It would be better if I could find a solution using jQuery, but not mandatory.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you do it the way you've proposed then you'll download the file locally and then upload it again (and I'm not convinced you can do that anyway, without user intervention).  It would make more sense to write an ASP.Net application on your target server that just downloads the files directly (twice as fast!)

Comment: Agree with @Archer this would work in node (I think) but your not going to get a users browser to do a "man in the middle" file transfer without it asking for user interaction as a security feature.

Comment: @PaulSwetz what security measure? You can very well do that, fortunately we don't need user gesture to download resources nor to post data to our servers. But, even if we can, that is indeed a very convoluted idea, and fetching only once on the end-server is indeed the best way if at all possible. If not (e.g because of credentials required) then please explain it as an [edit] to your question.